# writing information to a .txt file and getting None as my result

Tags: python

I am having trouble writing files to .txt files for a school project. I have included all my code for the project for reference. Any input would be greatly appreciated, but please make the input understandable to a beginner in python.

```
def first_letter_count(word, letter):
    for  number in word:
        if number[:1] in letter:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def check(letter):
    letter_count = 0
    fin = open('words.txt')
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        if first_letter_count(word, letter):
            letter_count += 1
    print str(letter) + ": " + str(letter_count) 


alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
oldstdout = sys.stdout
newfile = open('words_writing.txt', 'w')
for letter in alphabet:
    newfile.write(str(check(letter)))
newfile.close()
newfile2 = open('words_writing.txt', 'r')
```

Comment: Your function, check, doesn't return anything.  It only prints something to the screen -- if you want newfile.write(str(check(letter))) to work, you'll need to make your check function return the appropriate value to use elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `newfile.write(str(check(letter)))`, you are calling `newfile.write(None)`, since check doesn't return anything. Instead of your `print` statement at the end of `check`, try putting a `return`:

```
def first_letter_count(word, letter):
    for  number in word:
        if number[:1] in letter:
            return True
        else:
            return False

def check(letter):
    letter_count = 0
    fin = open('words.txt')
    for line in fin:
        word = line.strip()
        if first_letter_count(word, letter):
            letter_count += 1
    return str(letter) + ": " + str(letter_count) 


alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
oldstdout = sys.stdout
newfile = open('words_writing.txt', 'w')
for letter in alphabet:
    newfile.write(str(check(letter)))
newfile.close()
newfile2 = open('words_writing.txt', 'r')
```

---

Non-returning function demo:

```
>>> def multiply(num1, num2):
...     print num1 * num2 #Notice the print, not return
... 
>>> x = multiply(5, 6)
30
>>> print x
None
>>> def multiply(num1, num2):
...     return num1 * num2 #Notice the return this time
... 
>>> x = multiply(5, 6)
>>> print x
30
>>>
```